# Class template with variable variables

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have been reading about templates. I'm wondering if the following is possible:

The class has a variable number of variables, each created by the addition of a templated method who take as input a particular type.

Ex, we add template method which takes in type A and we want type A to be appended to an internal list pntrA[10] of A*. The key idea is we don't know if this method will exist or not until it is called, so we want the template/compiler to add pntrA[10] the class automatically.

```
Class FunctionStub
{
&ObjClass::myPtr;
int add_method(&ObjClass::method methodPtr)
{
    myPtr = methodPtr;
}

int run_method()
{
     //run myPtr
}
}
```

This is related to my prior question, I believe it could also be solved with std::function but I have some custom functionality I want to add.

One solution is to make FunctionStub a derived class where the base class has run_method() and the template would be used to create derived classes which attach the particular class type. But it would be way nicer to figure out if the compiler can be made to automatically add the relevant variables in a single class.

To give an example of what I want to do I want it to act as a container for generic object members and allow you to check the ID of the object member, ex:

```
myContainer container;

container.AttachMember(&Object::MemberFunction);

container.Contains(&Object::MemberFunction);

container.Remove(&Object::MemberFunction);

container.ExecuteContainedMember();
```

The point is I want to be able to just not have a list of generic member functions but I want to be able to add/remove them at will simply using the member definition(&Object::MemberFunction).

Comment: Lots of things are possible. Can you give examples of what the concrete instantiations would look like? Also, lists are a runtime thing, templates are a compile time thing. That said, what does that have to do with the STL (original or synonym for C++ standard library)?

Comment: I would rather the define the class in terms of the types being stored and then generate the method types based on the types being stored. Have a look at `std::tuple` this type allows you to specify the types you want to store as a list of template parameters.

Comment: Imagine that you were able to implement this exactly the way you envision it, somehow. Show an example of how you would use this facility, once available. This way, it might become clearer what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: What about the good-old `std::tuple` ? Every new template parameter add a variable of that type. You can access the internal list through `std::get<index>()`

Comment: I added kind of an overview of what I want to do.

Comment: Where will `run_method` get the object of `ObjClass` needed to call the member function? If the member function has parameters, where will it get the arguments to pass in? How does the "type `A`" you talked about fit in to the wanted usage?

Comment: I second trying Igor's suggestion: Don't show us code attempting to implement the tool, show us code using the tool, which would be complete and compilable if the tool had an implementation.

Comment: I tried to provide an example of the end object I want to create